# Rails schedule daily email task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I'm running into issues sending e-mails for overdue books using a task in rails.

I have done the following:

created a

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def overdue_books
        @user = params[:user]
        @checkout_logs = params[:checkout_logs]
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'You have overdue books')
    end
end
```

the following namespace and task

email.rake:

```
namespace :email do
  desc "send out emails for overdue books"
  task overdue_books: :environment do
    User.find_each do |user|      
      @checkout_logs = CheckoutLog.joins(:book).where(checkout_logs: {user_id: user.id, returned_date: nil}).where(CheckoutLog.arel_table[:due_date].lt(Time.now))
      UserMailer.with(user: user, checkout_logs: @checkout_logs).overdue_books.deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

as well as

overdue_books.html.erb:

```
<p><%= @user.email %> ,please visit the library and return the following overdue book(s):</p> 

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>BookId</th>
      <th>BookNumber</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>CheckoutDate</th>
      <th>DueDate</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @checkout_logs.each do |checkout_log| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.id %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.book_number %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.book.title %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.checkout_date %></td>
        <td><%= checkout_log.due_date %></td>        
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

also added to
Gemfile:

```
gem 'whenever', require: false
```

schedule.rb

```
set :output, "log/cron.log"
set :environment, "development"
every :day, at: ["12:00 AM"] do
    rake "email:overdue_books"
end
```

I tested out (from email.rake)

```
@checkout_logs = CheckoutLog.joins(:book).where(checkout_logs: {user_id: user.id, returned_date: nil}).where(CheckoutLog.arel_table[:due_date].lt(Time.now))
```

and made sure it correctly finds the test data I created.

So when I finally run

```
rails email:overdue_books --trace
```

it takes a few seconds and says

** Invoke email:overdue_books (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute email:overdue_books

but the server doesn't display sending e-mails and there are no e-mails send to the users in question.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try by sending Simple Email by Direct calling on Console Using  UserMailer.with(user: user, checkout_logs: @checkout_logs).overdue_books.deliver_now

Comment: Did you checked the `log/cron.log` for errors?

Comment: Just to make sure, you did run `whenever --update-crontab`?

Comment: Please show your smtp settings in `config/environments/development.rb` with `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`.

Comment: I think whenever use prod when running tasks but you are setting it to development? What are your dev settings for email?